# how to create environment variables to use in a .sh Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, sh

I’m triying this to create my variable for use in my script

```
        $process = new Process(['export USER_NAME='.$user->email]);
        $process->run();
        $process = new Process(['../example.sh']);
        $process->run();
```

But when I put this in my .sh

```
echo hola $USER_NAME bebe
```

this is the return

```
"hola bebe\n"
```

Comment: Does `new Process(['env USER_NAME=' . $user->email . ' ../example.sh']);` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I concatenate all in one string with out using enviroment Variables. So I dont found another the way to use variables for a command line.

```
    use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
    class NexmoController extends Controller
    {
    
        public function getJwt(User $id){
        $command = 'curl -X "POST" "https://api.nexmo.com/beta/users" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer "'.$JWT.' \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d $\'{ "name": "'.$user->email.'", "display_name": "'.$user->name.'"}\'';
        
        $ssh = new SSH2('shhServerExample.org');
        
        if (!$ssh->login('sshUser', 'shhPassword'))
        {
            $process= 'Login Failed';
        }
        else
        {
            $JWT = $ssh->exec($JWT);
            echo $JWT;
            $process= $ssh->exec($command);
        }
        return response()->json($process, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!